# Commercial Paper Asset History report won't display from VSCode HLF plugin

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibp-vscode-extension

Following the excellent tutorial here: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/queries-commercial-paper-smart-contract-ibm-blockchain-vscode-extension/

When I get to Step 7 the commercial paper asset history report won't display when I invoke index.html as described in Step 7.3

The results.json file *does* have what looks like the correct data from the tutorial.

Have tried with both firefox 68.0.2 and safari 12.1.2 - while I get the Tabular commercial report all the tx data is blank - but it is in the results.json file

Thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: The issue is [CORs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp) updated recently in Firefox. While there are methods/etc elsewhere allowing you to 'disable' CORs, I wouldn't recommend. The sole purpose of this tutorial is for demo, (didn't setup a web server to serve this one page locally - whereas the 'norm' in everyday scenarios would be to serve content via a web server and http/https request).

Comment: I've updated the code at the repo at https://github.com/mahoney1/commpaper - so you'll need to re-clone. If you execute the history query again(regenerating the `results.json` using new `queryapp.js`) file, you should be able to load/render the data in HTML (using the new `index.html`)